# Background image full

Tags: html, css

My site > [My site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q6WZ.jpg)

Similar site > [Similar Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geJ4H.jpg)

I need to make my site similar but with different images.

I don't have much experience with HTML or CSS and I need fast this site work
Take all the code so I don't know where the error might be, I hope you help me with this question.

Thanks

```
        <title>Gerência de Governança de TI</title>
        <style> 
          img 
          { 
          margin:0px 100px 100px 80px; 
          } 
       </style> 
      </head>
 <body >
            <div class="container" id ="c1">

                 <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                       <img src="../Site/logo.png">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm col-md-4">
                        Gerência de Tecnologia de Informação
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm col-md-4">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div> 
             </div>

             <div class="container" id="c2">
                (min-width: 380px) {
                  .container {
                     width: 100%;
                     margin: 0;
                     padding: 0;
                  }
               }
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-sm col-md-3">

                    </div>
                       <div class="col-sm col-md-12">
                          <h5  id="demo"> </h5>                                
                      </div>
                </div>                       
             </div>

             <h1> Aço especial também é feito com informação !</h1>

                  <div class="container-fluid">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h3> A Gerência de Tecnologia de 

    </body>
```

Comment: provide a valid code please !

Comment: jsfiddle.net/hx5mb0nq My code complete. Thank's

Comment: You have to correct you whole code, here nobody will code for you. You have to much errors in your code

Comment: I'm not asking to code for myself, I just want for a borderless background image and paddings

Answer (score 1):

your code har a lots of problems like css not wrapper in

For what about your question, the better way to have the full image background is to use background property

```
.container{
 background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/any); 
 background-size:cover;
 width:100%;
 height:100vh;
}
```

see this fiddle that I've made with a modified version of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/6qkmvL83/